# Why are dataverse lookup primary name columns null when brought into a data flow in data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataverse

In Dataverse, there are the columns suffixed with "name" that take the value of the primary name column of the associated lookup. I'm trying to filter on one of these columns, but all of the values being brought into data factory are null. When I check the database, these columns definitely have values. This lack of values doesn't appear to just be in the data preview as, even though my data flow runs, it doesn't output anything.

[image]

The content of the filter is as follows:

```
in(['Stephanie ...', 'Karen ...', 'Rachel ...', 'Cameron ...', 'Patrick ...', 'Hannah ...', 'Rebecca ...', 'Simon ...', 'Mihaela ...', 'Kate ...', 'Toby ...'], ptl_feeearnername)
```

The data preview from the select looks like this
[image]

Here's a subset of the data in the database

| ptl_matterid | ptl_partner | ptl_partnername | ptl_feeearner | ptl_feeearnername |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADD60453-CA81-4BBC-8E2A-A4B368CB8812 | D5806CED-A4FA-4171-9968-A171027E9FE1 | Becki ... | C91C3F8B-38C0-4A21-B7CB-FD164D2C0880 | Patrick ... |
| 308C4899-6BCA-4253-B1D3-96B651D9FE03 | 2DB19836-6A87-4267-855A-8F0BEBC9F355 | Dan ... | A3A50C3E-B405-4662-A8CB-357A04EC6CAB | Rachel ... |

The query I use to get this data is

```
select ptl_matterid, ptl_partner, ptl_partnername, ptl_feeearner, ptl_feeearnername
from ptl_matterid
```

Is there any reason why these values will be null when brought into a data flow in data factory?

The associated lookup column (containing the GUID foreign key to the other table) does contain a value when brought in from dataverse, so I could filter on that. However, for readability of my data flow, I'd prefer to filter on the name column.

When there is no filter on the data flow, the flow also runs fine and outputs values into the sink.

Comment: Lookups will not store the value in the table. It will just refer the value of associated table. It is better to bring that associated table in dataflow and use `join` or `lookup` transformation and bring the associated values

Comment: I guess, data preview of source transformation itself will have null values only.

Comment: @Aswin Ah okay, so even though the value is returned when I do a SQL query without a join, it's not actually stored in the table?

Comment: 1) Does your source transformation data preview has values for these name columns?

Comment: @Aswin No, the source data preview doesn't show values for these name columns

Comment: When there is no filter on the data flow, the flow also runs fine and outputs values into the sink. --- **This is confusing. Could you explain it ?**

Comment: @Aswin Sorry that it's confusing. I just meant that when I don't filter using those name columns the data can travel through the data flow into the sink. I more wanted to highlight that the issue was that those columns were null, rather than some other configuration issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup columns do not store the actual values in the table, but instead refer to the values in the associated table. The "name" columns in Dataverse are virtual columns that are generated by the system based on the primary name column of the associated lookup. This is the reason you can query the data without using join.

But if you want to use the values of the associated table in your Data Factory data flow, you need to bring in the associated table and use a join or lookup transformation to combine the data. Only then, you can get the values of the columns whose value depends on the associated table.